# Inspecting and clearing .NET MemoryCache. RAM keeps building up

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, memorycache

We use the .NET memorycache for big collections of data. We need the cache to sometimes clear and we use
`Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.Default.Remove("keyhere")`
for that. Unfortunately i see almost no drop in the amount of RAM used by w3wp.exe, which build up to about 64GB during the day before it recycles the entire pool and everyone loses their session_ID and have to login to our application again.

I have tried running

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
GC.Collect()
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

But this seems to have no effect.

Clearing the entire cache with

```
Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.Default.Trim(100)
```

Also barely makes any difference.

I feel like a lot of collections just remain in the RAM without being actually used or referenced by any of the cache entries / keys.

How do i make sure there is no memory leak or that collections are stored multiple times? Or is there a way to find out what collections (with keys and sizes) the memorycache/w3wp.exe RAM is filled with at some point?

Im quite lost at this point.

Edit: Example of how i currently add a collection to the cache (VB.NET):

```
Private m_Companies_All As Core._CompanyCollection
        //<summary>Gets all Active Companies that are available within the current CustomerConfig</summary>
        Public Property Companies_All As Core._CompanyCollection Implements ICustomerConfig.Companies_All
            Get
                Dim xCacheKey As String = Me.CacheKey("Core.Companies_All")
                Dim xCacheItem As Runtime.Caching.CacheItem = Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.Default.GetCacheItem(xCacheKey)
                If xCacheItem Is Nothing Then
                    m_Companies_All = Core._CompanyCollection.All(Core._Company.eStates.Active, Me)
                    xCacheItem = New Runtime.Caching.CacheItem(xCacheKey, m_Companies_All) // Add CacheItem to the Cache for 20m 
                    Dim xCachePolicy As New Runtime.Caching.CacheItemPolicy With {.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20)}

                    //Insert into Cache 
                    Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.Default.Add(xCacheItem, xCachePolicy)
                End If

                //xItem Is Not Nothing 
                m_Companies_All = xCacheItem.Value
                Return m_Companies_All
            End Get
            Set(value As Core._CompanyCollection)
                m_Companies_All = value
            End Set
        End Property
```

Comment: Have you profiled the memory use? https://michaelscodingspot.com/memory-profilers-principles/

Comment: `Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.Default.Trim(100)` are you in fact using the default cache?

Comment: Could you show how you add a typical big-collection entry in the cache?

Comment: I edited the original post with an Example. I am indeed using the default cache. Is this bad practice? And if so, why?

Comment: "it recycles the entire pool and everyone loses their session_ID" -> use out-of-process session state to avoid the session state being lost on a recycle event. E.g. [Out-of-Process Session State (In State Server) in ASP.NET](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2124ae/out-of-process-session-state-in-state-server-in-Asp-Net/).

Comment: Have you tried adding a [CacheItemPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.cacheitempolicy) to automatically expire cache items?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a class called clsMemory and write this code:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class clsMemory
    <DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL", EntryPoint:="SetProcessWorkingSetSize", SetLastError:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Friend Shared Function SetProcessWorkingSetSize(ByVal pProcess As IntPtr, ByVal dwMinimumWorkingSetSize As Integer, ByVal dwMaximumWorkingSetSize As Integer) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL", EntryPoint:="GetCurrentProcess", SetLastError:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
Friend Shared Function GetCurrentProcess() As IntPtr
    End Function

    Public Sub New()
        Dim pHandle As IntPtr = GetCurrentProcess()
        SetProcessWorkingSetSize(pHandle, -1, -1)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then in some Form window just add a button and write this:

```
 Dim MemClass As New clsMemory()
 MemClass = Nothing
```

Maybe it will work for you as it works for me for many years.